# Infinite product $\Gamma(\tfrac14)=\mathrm{A}^3e^{-\mathrm{G}/\pi}2^{1/6}\sqrt{\pi}\prod_{k\ge1}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k}$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, riemann-zeta, infinite-product, constants

I saw the following infinite product on Wikipedia:
$$\Gamma\left(\tfrac14\right)=\mathrm{A}^3e^{-\mathrm{G}/\pi}2^{1/6}\sqrt{\pi}\prod_{k\ge1}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k}\tag{1}$$
where $\mathrm A$ is the Glaisher constant, and $\mathrm G$ is Catalan's constant. I am looking for a proof of this product.

I haven't gotten very far with this product, other than noting that if
$$\zeta_*(s)=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac1{(1-\frac1{2k})^{(-1)^k ks}}$$
then 
$$\zeta_*'(0)=3\ln\mathrm A+\frac16\ln2+\frac12\ln\pi-\frac{\mathrm{G}}{\pi}-\ln\Gamma\left(\tfrac14\right),\tag2$$
of course, assuming that $(1)$ is true. Perhaps $(2)$ is easier to prove. Could I have some help? Thanks.

Comment: Related problem: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3147649/closed-form-of-prod-n-1-infty-left-fracnn1-right-1n-1n/3148194#3148194) --- you can use the definition of $A$ for your proof (*it's only a hint*)

Comment: You can find a solution with the *Borwein-Dykshoorn function*, e.g. [here](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P67.pdf) (whole script) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1305.6247v3.pdf), page 3 . $~~$ *N O T E*: $~\prod_{k\ge1}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k}$ (<- *not* defined !) has two solutions, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k}$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\prod_{k=1}^{2n+1}\left(1-\frac1{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*A short proof.*

$\displaystyle Q_0(x) :=\Gamma(x+1)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^x}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)}~~ , ~~~~ Q_1(x) :=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{e^{xn}n^{-x^2/2}}{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac{x}{k}\right)^k}$

$\displaystyle \pi^{1/2} = Q_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)~~ , ~~ A^3  = 2^{7/12}Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 ~~ , ~~ e^{G/\pi} = 2^{3/4}\left(\frac{ Q_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) Q_1\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) }{ Q_0\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)  }\right)^2$

It follows:

$\displaystyle \prod\limits_{k=1}^{2n}\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{(-1)^k k} =  \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{4k}\right)^{2k}}{\left(1-\frac{1}{4k-2}\right)^{2k-1}} = \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^{2k-1} \left(1-\frac{1}{4k}\right)^{2k}}{ \left(1-\frac{3}{4k}\right)^{2k-1} } = $

$\displaystyle = \frac{ \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{3}{4k}\right) n^{-1/2} }{ n^{-3/4} \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right) } \left(\frac{ e^{-3n/4} n^{-9/32} \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{2k}\right)^k \prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{1}{4k}\right)^k }{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \left(1-\frac{3}{4k}\right)^k  e^{-n/2} n^{-1/8} e^{-n/4} n^{-1/32} }\right)^2$

$\displaystyle \to  ~\frac{ Q_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) }{ Q_0\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) } \left(\frac{ Q_1\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) }{ Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right) }\right)^2$

$\displaystyle = 2^{-1/6} \frac{ Q_0\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) }{ Q_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) } \cdot 2^{-7/12} Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{-2} \cdot 2^{3/4} \left(\frac{ Q_0\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) Q_1\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) }{ Q_0\left(-\frac{3}{4}\right) Q_1\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)}\right)^2$

$\displaystyle = \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{4}\right) 2^{-1/6} \pi^{-1/2} A^{-3} e^{G/\pi}$

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you (+1)

Comment: @clathratus: You are welcome. ;)

Comment: do you have any references for the $e^{\mathrm G/\pi}$ identity?

Comment: E.g. [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042798001927), page 195, first formula. But this doesn't look understandable if one doesn't deal in detail with the derivation of the zeta function. Use [Catalan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan's_constant), section "Relation to other special functions" (Barnes), with more details [Clausen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clausen_function), section "Relation to the Barnes' G-function" .

Comment: And: The formula in the script of Kurokawa gives you the opportunity to deduce everything yourself, but unfortunately it is formulated unnecessarily cumbersome, [Kurokawa](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pja/1195512182)
page 62, combination of the product formula for $F_r(z)$ and formula $(4)$ .

Comment: @clathratus why did you downvote ? my answer is definitively how you should think to those formulas, they are completely useless, the only interesting point is to know they follow from taking the formal expressions and massaging to make them convergent, simplifying the different irrational constants involved when possible.

Comment: @reuns If you hover your cursor over the downvote button, it says "This answer is not useful." In your answer, you yourself say "I don't think giving more details is useful." Twice, I asked for more details, and twice, you refused.  Frankly, I find that completely useless.

Answer (score -4):

The log of the product can be expressed in term of $\frac12\beta'(-1)-\frac12 \beta'(0)$ and  $\frac12\eta'(-1)$

where $\beta(s) = \sum_{k\ge 0} (2k+1)^{-s} (-1)^k$ 
, it is a L-function with a functional equation.

$G =\beta(2)$, $\log A = 1/12-\zeta'(-1)$

Finally $e^{\beta'(0)}$ can be expressed in term of $\Gamma(1/4)$ and $\Gamma(1/2)$ infinite products.

I don't think giving more details is useful.

Comment: I think more details would be useful. For instance, what are the relations between $\zeta_*(s)$ and $\beta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$?

Comment: Your $\zeta_*(s)$ doesn't make any sense. No more details won't be useful, I made clear the needed theorems

Comment: Could you *at least* show the relation between the log of the product and the various constants you mentioned? What you have as an 'answer' barely gives me any information.

Comment: Formally the relation is obvious